# What would be the best way to use python's functions from excel?

Tags: python, excel

*Somebody really needs to fix this "subjective questions evaluator"*

I usually compile my functions in a DLL and call them from excel. That works fine (well, let's just say it works)

Unfortunatelly, python cannot be compiled. I know of py2exe but I don't know that it can make a DLL.

So, ..., is there any other way ? I appreciate all ideas and suggestions on the matter.

Comment: See here for the magic of the subjective questions evaluator: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435

Comment: :) yeah, thanks. I'll avoid the mentioned words in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Excel Addin that allows you to do this called [Discovery Script](http://www.xefion.com/getting_started_diss.html) at xefion.com.

It's free but not open source. It's also based on the IronPython implementation.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to write a COM server in Python, and call that from Excel. There are tutorials describing [Win32 COM servers](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartServerCom.html), and [screencasts on calling such servers from Excel](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=2190050&fromSeriesID=219).

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not a possible solution for you, but there is the [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/products/resolver-one/) spreadsheet application (which is like Excel combined with Python). It is not connected with Excel in any way, but claims to be compatible to some extent.

Comment: Resolver One looks like an excellent product, but it is totally separate from Excel. However, if the OP doesn't need to share his or her spreadsheet as an actual Excel document, it might be perfect. Any Python code should just drop right in, and be called from the worksheet just like VBA would be in Excel.

Comment: Yes, it is separate, I clarified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I do need an excel compatibility. I waas hoping to avoid rewriting python code which I have now into fortran, and then compiling it to a dll, but according to these experiences, that will be the case.

Comment: I think the compatibility is limited to the ability to import an Excel spreadsheet into Resolver One, but not the other way around.

Comment: (Full disclosure: I'm a Resolver Systems employee)

You can import Excel sheets into Resolver One, and then export them in Excel format, either with formulae or converting all of the formulae into their results.  It also supports many Excel functions, and (as you mention fortran) we also support NumPy in the grid -- eg. a cell can contain a NumPy array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Giles, Thanks for the correction. I mainly meant that you can't do something nifty in Python/Resolver and export the full functionality back to Excel. Is that correct? I'm looking for a way to use Resolver One on a commercial project but so many people are determined that "spreadsheet" = "Excel"...

Answer (score 4):

Im surprised nobody mentioned [pyxll](http://www.pyxll.com/).  From the website:

> PyXLL is an Excel addin that enables functions written in Python to be
>   called in Excel. Python functions can either be exposed as Excel user
>   defined functions that can be called from worksheets, as custom menu
>   items, or as macros.

Comment: Just noticed your answer. I currently don't have Excel installed, so cannot try it, but does this enables you to write python functions and use them in MS Excel? Using data in cells? Have I understood correctly? If so, :)))

Comment: yes it does that exactly, works great.  But not free for commercial use.

Comment: Yeah, saw that mentioned somewhere. Wouldn't have taken too much space if they actually mentioned a figure for commercial use somewhere, and said, until then - it's "nagware". Gonna eval. it a bit more, see how it goes.

Comment: pyxll is a great way to go - I've used it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any py2dll similar to py2exe.

However, you could create a dll in C and use the [Very High Level Layer](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html) to call your script. I don't know it is an acceptable solution for you. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this some years back. My solution was to run small Python server that exported the functions using SOAP, then call the functions using Visual Basic's SOAP library. The advantage is that you don't have to ship a Python environment with your spreadsheets. The disadvantage is that the clients will need a network connection.