# How to update an Excel worksheet live without closing and reopening python

Tags: python, excel

I'm designing a trade management system. I want to be able to enter in values into excel and have python do some computation (rather than excel). Is this even possible?

With openpyxl I have to enter in the value to excel, save, close, run the script, reopen excel. This is an unacceptable in terms of the design criteria.

Can any one recommend a better way to have a live interface which updates when values are changed in the cells ? Ideally I would like to remain with excel

Comment: Can you switch to VBA?  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/409434/2877364

Comment: You can create a VBA Add-In that provides a hook or interface with a Python EXE. This way, Excel process is calling on the Python process via COM.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1322962/1467082)

Comment: you can use excel marco that save sheet every 2 second https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545317/save-excel-file-in-every-2-second-without-using-macro

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is even possible, but it will be at least *difficult* to do. Because Excel locks the sheet file when it is read, it cannot be modified by other processes while it is opened. 
So that leave only the possibility to have the Excel process modify the file. And scripting in Excel can only be done in VB as far as I know (but I don't know much about that).